# Insert Into table ommitting columns that have default values

Tags: postgresql, insert, subquery, default-value

I have a PostgreSQL database with lots of tables of the same structure, 36 columns in total:

```
CREATE TABLE some_schema.some_table    (
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('some_schema.id_seq'::regclass),
    col2,
    col3,
    col4,
    [...],
    col35,
    mi_prinx integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('some_schema.mi_prinx_seq'::regclass),
    CONSTRAINT some_table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (mi_prinx)
)
```

In many instances I will have to insert records from another table with the same structure:

```
INSERT INTO some_schema.some_table (col2,col3...col35)
    SELECT col2,col3...col35
    FROM some_schema.another_table_with_same_structure;
```

Is there a way of doing this without having to list all columns that don't have a default value? I think I can use `DEFAULT VALUES` somehow but I can't get the syntax right based on the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way of doing this without having to list all columns that don't have a default value?

No you either insert all the columns using the `*` expansion,

```
INSERT INTO foo 
  SELECT * FROM bar;
```

Or, you insert just the listed columns

```
INSERT INTO foo (col2,col3)
  SELECT col2, col3
  FROM bar;
```

You can also use `DEFAULT` to be explicit, but no one does that. It's in the spec however, *Each column not present in the explicit or implicit column list will be filled with a default value, either its declared default value or null if there is none.* Being explicit looks like this.

```
INSERT INTO foo (col1,col2,col3)
  SELECT DEFAULT, col2, col3
  FROM bar;
```

`DEFAULT COLUMNS` sets all columns to their respective default. From the docs on `DEFAULT COLUMNS`,

> DEFAULT VALUES, All columns will be filled with their default values.

```
CREATE TABLE foo (id serial, foo serial, bar serial);
INSERT INTO foo (id,foo,bar) VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO foo DEFAULT VALUES;
INSERT INTO foo(id,foo,bar) VALUES (42,42,DEFAULT);

TABLE foo;
 id | foo | bar 
----+-----+-----
  1 |   1 |   1
  2 |   2 |   2
 42 |  42 |   3
(3 rows)
```

Comment: So if you were to use an explicit `SELECT DEFAULT, col2, col3` statement, would this mean 2 separate calls to the implicit `nextval` function, once when you select, again when you insert?

Comment: No, just the single call. It just looks weird and no one uses that syntax.

Comment: I'm getting "*DEFAULT is not allowed in this context*" when trying to use `DEFAULT` in a `SELECT` clause. Has this changed?

Comment: @Bergi what database and version?

Comment: @EvanCarroll PostgreSQL 12.2. Same on Postgres 13: [online demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=645e64a2210b77d1cf297659647acfbd)

Comment: Running into the same problem (not allowed in this context). Any ideas?

Comment: @EvanCarroll it doesn't seem it ever worked in Postgresql?